# A girl who [told] him that he [was] good-looking does not exist - are the verbs conditional usage?

Tags: tense, conditionals

**Example 1**

> A girl who **is going to** help you with your study and all of your trouble does not exist.

**Example 2**

> A girl who **told** him that he **was** good-looking does not exist.

The reasons (because-clauses) are my guesses, so they can be imaginary.

So this got me to think: Does this kind of structure have anything to do with a second or third conditional structure or are they just normal past tense and future tense?

Are parts in bold correct?

Comment: They are nothing to do with conditionals. You are just using clauses to describe that non-existent girl.

Comment: To expand on what Kate said, the topic of your sentence has nothing to do with the grammar. Using the words "does not exist" does not change the grammar to *unreal*. You need proper grammar structures like *[ "if" + simple past ]* or equivalent.

Comment: Almost all conditional sentences require an if. A few don't but those usually imply it. [If[ he were to leave, we would know it.

Comment: Question is very unclear. Recommended action is to remove one example and only ask one question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 could work if you change "A girl" to "The girl". That way, you can express the fact that he was delusional, since he told you about a compliment from a non-existent person.

If you want Example 2 to sound like Example 1 (i.e. no girl would ever compliment him), you would need to say, "A girl who would tell him that he was good-looking didn't exist."